# Jess rule engine clear function performance

Tags: rules, jess

I am using  Jess clear() function and it has a slow  performance problem (100ms for every call and because i have to use it 20 times it is 2 seconds estimated time). Is there something alternative (a function to shut down the jess engine, or a function to delete all templates, facts and rules) which i can use for higher performance?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a little on how you run your application. If you call Jess from a Java application, you can simply

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){ // 20 times
    jess.Rete rete = new jess.Rete();
    // load functions, templates, rules, facts,...
    rete.run();
}
```

Rather than

```
jess.Rete rete = new jess.Rete();
// load functions
for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){ // 20 times    
    // load templates, rules, facts,...
    rete.run();
    rete.clear();
}
```

But note that, depending on the number of your facts and Pojos, either procedure may delete lots of Java objects, with the usual consequence. But you won't be able to avoid that, and it isn't a Jess problem either.

Comment: Yes i use Java, i changed the code but it does not work

Comment: Surely not in one of the statements I posted. If some of your code doesn't fit the suggested approach you'll have to adapt it. After all, you didn't post any code, so how am I to know what goes on?